# How to change text color to transparent in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I want to change the text color in UITextView with transparent. From many forum, we just set the text color with clear color. When I set text color in XIB with clear color, the text color doesn't change to transparent but change to black. But when i set with othe color, the text color change to the color I choose. Any body can help fix my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[textView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:YES];
```

This should make the text invisible but still allow you to type and use all other features of the `UITextView`.

Answer (score 2):

try set:

```
yourTextView.alpha = 0.6 // or any positive float value < 1.00
```

Comment: if I set the alpha, it's change the view not the text color. I just need the transparent in text color not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your text color alpha value:

```
  yourTextView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
```

UPDATE::

```
myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTextView.alpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: When I set the alpha of text color with number beetween 0 and 1, it's can't change the text color to transparent. It's like nothing.

Answer (score 0):

What about pseudo-transparency? Set the text-color to a color which is between the opaque text-color and the background-color of your text-view.